# How to make a stepper like in image in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

How can I achieve this kind of stepper as shown in the image? I have tried the stepper widget and some packages but was unable to achieve that
[image: Design]

Answer (score 2):

You can use package [status_change 2.0.0](https://pub.dev/packages/status_change) to achive this view

Here is the [example](https://github.com/usamaaelgendy/status_change/tree/master/example/lib/example_horizontal/view) for horizontal view

Comment: how can I use it? there is no proper example is given

Comment: I have added example, please check

Comment: Not useful at all. I am wasting my time on this from yesterday but didn't solve the issue of this package. The example that you gave is not useful. It has a run time error that says unexpected null value. I have tried a lot but can't solve this issue

Comment: Have you try stepper widget?